# 3D WebPortal for a large amount of data

Tags: arcgis-server, 3d

I am looking to create a 3D WebPortal for my client. My organisation has ArcGIS for Server so we would be looking for the easiest way to deploy using this (although open to other suggestions).

There is potentially a large amount of data...DTM/DSM, 3D buildings, Aerial Imagery and many vector datasets.

Have any of you deployed something like this before. I guess the key problem is the '3D part. Currently we supply a standalone appplication that uses ArcGIS Explorer, but they now want this across the organisation as a webportal. Or maybe served from our server to ArcGIS Explorer, if that can be done?

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I recommend keeping abreast of **[CityEngine Web Viewer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgisonline/index.html#//010q000000nw000000)** and **[ArcGIS 3D Analyst for Server](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisserver/extensions/3d-extension)**.

Comment: Unfortunately 3D CityEngine is limited on data size and also the data needs to be stored in the ESRI cloud, which is currently a no no. Ideally the site could be hosted by ArcGIS for Server.....but happy for other suggestions. Looking at 20GB of data....